# FireBase, DatabaseError: Permission denied (Again)

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, permissions

I am trying for a while to connect to FireBase and I`m always getting to

> DatabaseError: Permission denied.

I know that this is a question that many asked and might be a duplicate, but as you can see I did almost everything.

My Java code:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
enter code here`myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

- I Did all the stpes of Tools>FireBase>RealTime DB
- I did all the steps of **Add Firebase to your Android app** (Register app -> "DownLoad config file" and put it in the app folder. -> "Add Firebase SDK" (just higher versions) -> Manually synced Gradle -> Than "Run your app to verify installation" , but **here it was stuck and was just waiting also after I started my app**
- I tried via almost all StackOverFlow to give full access to every one:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should replace this line of code. hope you get the point.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad Aslan, but again this did not work... same problem...

Comment: what dependencies you used?  i think you never used     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin                       this dependency in your project level (build.gradle) file inside dependencies . because 2nd. you should use https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file documentation instead of sdk implementation because sdk did not implement google dependencies as i mentioned

Comment: then again make sure you put  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in your manifest file

Comment: if you are using firebase assistant in your android studio then follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#assistant this documentation step by step... hope it helps